# How to use location.hash as a selector for variant elements in a page

Tags: html, hash, selector

Is there a native way to target the nth element on a page by using http://site.tld/page.html#select(h3:nth(5))

I could think of so many reasons why this would not be acceptable to exist as a feature in HTML, but this is not the issue here.

So if it is not possible to achieve in HTML, would be possible to do using some feature build in specific browser like Chrome or Firefox ?

It's that sometimes, I wanna point people to a certain section of a page, but when I go through the code there is no id="paragraph4" or even a  and I find it very upsetting not being able to do things like these.

Comment: I've thought about this as well for references in research documents, +1'd it :)

Comment: Thank you, hope we find a solution to this then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after 8 years :

There is a draft by WICG for **[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match)**, and now you can link to text on a page as if you were searching for it by adding the following to the hash

`#:~:text=<Text To Link to>`

Working example on `Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138`:

[Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10418618/614277#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link) Should reload the page and highlight the link's text

Answer (score 1):

This won't really answer your question (I think), but I believe that only a browser extension could achieve this kind of behaviour, i.e. the consumer end.

The extension could also assist you in selecting the part that you want and generate a specially crafted URL that you can bookmark or share.

However, to share this feature with others, you would have to make them install the extension too (and for different browsers).

Comment: Well this is a nice alternative to what I am willing to achieve at least. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Proposals
Quoting...

"Up until Firefox 5, Firefox supported XPath links such as #xpath:/html/body/div[3] which could be used in conjunction with a bookmarklet such as http://antimatter15.com/wp/2009/11/xpath-bookmark-bookmarklet/ to link within HTML documents that lacked proper IDs. This feature was removed as part of a code cleanup in Mozilla bug #457102"

(bug link dropped from the quote due to stackoverflow not wanting me to post 3 links)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to grab `document.location.hash`, parse the value and execute the appropriate code in JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not really what I was saying. Say I read an article and I want to point to the last paragraph on taht page, and make you read it instantly by following the http://site.tld/page.html#select(h3:nth(5)) link. The problem is that I can't edit the code of a website that is not mine to achieve such a thing. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: I know what you mean, but what you wish to happen is not possible.